# Генерация текста

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe2

Данный код генерирует текст по такому принципу:

Есть шаблон к примеру:

**ru.stackoverflow.com - {лучший|классный|восхитительный} форум - {2019|2020|2022} года**

После, генерация идет только по первым ключевым словам, что между скобок {}, то есть так:

```
ru.stackoverflow.com - лучший форум - {2019|2020|2022} года
ru.stackoverflow.com - классный форум - {2019|2020|2022} года
ru.stackoverflow.com - восхитительный форум -{2019|2020|2022} года
ru.stackoverflow.com - 2020 форум - {2019|2020|2022} года
ru.stackoverflow.com - 2022 форум - {2019|2020|2022} года
```

Как исправить код, чтобы генерация шла по всему шаблону, то есть на выходе получить:

```
ru.stackoverflow.com - лучший форум - 2019 года
ru.stackoverflow.com - классный форум - 2020 года
ru.stackoverflow.com - восхитительный форум - 2022 года
ru.stackoverflow.com - 2020 форум - 2019 года
ru.stackoverflow.com - 2022 форум - 2020 года
```

Вот, собственно, и код:

```
var
 s: string;
 ss: Tstringlist;
 i: integer;
begin
 ss:= Tstringlist.Create;
 s:=memo1.Lines.Strings[0];
 delete(S,1,pos('{',S));
 while pos('|',S)<>0 do
  Begin
   ss.Add(copy(S,1,pos('|',S)-1));
   delete(S,1,pos('|',S));
  End;
 ss.Add(copy(S,1,pos('}',S)-1));
 s:=copy(memo1.Lines.Strings[0],1,pos('-',memo1.Lines.Strings[0])-2);
 ss.Add(copy(memo1.Lines.Strings[0],
             pos('}',memo1.Lines.Strings[0])+2,
             length(memo1.Lines.Strings[0])));
 for i:=0 to ss.count-2 do
  memo1.Lines.Add(s+' '+ss.Strings[i]+' '+ss.Strings[ss.count-1]);
end;
end.
```

Comment: Вы делаете генератор дорвеев на delphi?

Comment: А, вы антиплагиат хотите обмануть?

Comment: Ну есть и более рабочие рецепты. Хотя, возможно, уже не актуальные. Смотрите, идете на сайт юникода или найдите любой сайт с таблицей символов в гугле, откройте разные алфавиты разных языков и меняйте похожие буквы русские на разные. Если будете делать это автоматически, полный список символов можно найти тут: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: @DiD, Уже проверяла по такой схеме unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt  и не проходит (Но за попытку помочь спасибо). К сожалению только размножение помогает еще но вот не могу настроить код.

Comment: На каких языках вы проверяли?

Comment: вы хотите мне сказать, [яндекс](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%E1%89%80%CE%BF%CF%81%CA%8D%CE%B1&lr=967) ничего не находит, а антиплагиат найдет? Вот нашел их вам [полный список](https://www.unicode.org/charts/), посмотрите как их много.

Comment: @DiD, Буду пробовать Спасибо. Но конечно же с кодом для генерации плохо что не получается его переделать как выше.

Comment: да [синонимайзеры](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&t=h_&ia=web) давно не работают. Хорошо это или плохо? Сказать сложно. Повторюсь, антиплагиат уже давно переводит слова в векторы, и похожие по смыслу слова переведутся в один верктор, и повторы работ сразу выкупят.

Comment: По моим данным, антиплагиатом занимались люди из Яндекса, все что не понимает Яндекс, запутает и антиплагиат

Comment: Используйте алфавиты много разных языков, миксуйте их

Comment: Вам надо написать программу, которая будет сравнивать оптическое представление всех UTF символов на степерь похожести с русским алфавитом. Используйте для проверки схожести распознавание [Tesseract](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract). Потом научную работу напишете по этой теме.

Comment: @DiD, Идея хорошая а вот как подобную программу сделать. Точнее сложно ли сделать ?

Comment: Не, это не сложно. Есть даже [web-версия](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) и [куча мануалов](https://proglib.io/p/tesseract-js-izvlekaem-tekst-iz-kartinok-s-pomoshchyu-javascript-2020-04-22). Хотя, для delphi я думаю будет чуточку сложнее найти гайд по tesseract. Но и на нём тоже можно: https://github.com/r1me/TTesseractOCR4